# sed remove part of all match occurrences

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file "names.xml" that looks like the below:

```
    NAME="James"
    NAME="Jack_DONE"
    NAME="John_DONE"
    NAME="Jimmy"
```

I want to use a single SED line command to find all occurrences of 'NAME="J' That has '_DONE' within the "" and I want to remove only the '_DONE' from all the matches found.

So the result should look like:

```
    NAME="James"
    NAME="Jack"
    NAME="John"
    NAME="Jimmy"
```

This is the command I am using:

```
sed 's/^[^#]\(.*\)NAME="J\(.*\)_DONE"/\1"NAME=J\2"/' names.xml
```

I am sure I can do this in a way more efficient way!
Your time and assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU sed: Only in lines that contain `NAME="J` search for `_DONE` and replace by nothing.

```
sed '/NAME="J/{s/_DONE//}' names.xml
```

Output:

```
    NAME="James"
    NAME="Jack"
    NAME="John"
    NAME="Jimmy"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak -r '/^#/!s/(NAME="J[^"]*)_DONE"/\1"/' file
NAME="James"
NAME="Jack"
NAME="John"
NAME="Jimmy"
```

Comment: just, maybe, add the `/^#/ !` in front, to exclude comment as in the sed  JP try

Answer (score 2):

Only a minor tweak is required to fix the position of the quotes and indentation:

```
sed 's/^\([^#].*\)NAME="J\(.*\)_DONE"/\1NAME="J\2"/' names.xml
```

Comment: assuming there is only `#Something` and `NAME` on each start of line in the file

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk '/NAME="J/ {sub(/_DONE/,"")}1' names.xml
    NAME="James"
    NAME="Jack"
    NAME="John"
    NAME="Jimmy"
```

To write it back yo the file:

```
awk '/NAME="J/ {sub(/_DONE/,"")}1' names.xml > tmp && mv tmp names.xml
```

or if you have `gnu awk >= 4.1`

```
awk -i '/NAME="J/ {sub(/_DONE/,"")}1' names.xml
```